# Magento REST Error 401 oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token

Tags: error, rest-api

Since a week i'm trying to get the **REST API** to work but without success, 
i searched the whole internet for a solution. Everytime when i try to connect to the **Magento REST API** i get the

> **Error 401 oauth_parameters_absent=oauth_token.**

I'm using the **firefox RESTClient** and i have 2 seperate Magento installations on different server with different versions (**1.7.0.2 & 1.9.0.1**) but on both systems the same error.

If i try to connect via the guest role, everything works fine but over the **oAuth i always get the 401 error**.

Maybe someone could help me im really getting desperate

Comment: Make sure you have roles enabled for customer and admin.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/63611/getting-403-forbidden-response-with-rest-api-on-ce-1-9-1-0/64429#64429

Comment: Have you authorised your consumer token?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the detail set-by-step instruction to test REST api via Firefox's RestClient:[Testing REST Resources](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest/testing_rest_resources.html)

Make sure you have already got these key parameters and filled in the

> Authentication->Oauth->signature for this request

- oauth_consumer_key
- oauth_consumer_secret
- oauth_token
- oauth_token_secret

Yes Magento 1.X is old and complex when doing REST stuffs, just keep calm and try, don't panic :)